# Number of edges in the simple graph with the given conditions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph on $n$ vertices $v_1,v_2...v_n$. Let $G-v_i$ is having $m_i$ edges for $1\leq i \leq n$. Then prove that $m=\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By handshake lemma we have $$\sum _{i=1}^n d_i = 2m$$

For each $i$ we have $$m_i = m-d_i$$
where $d_i$ is degree of $i$-th node. Now if we sum this over all $i$ we get

$$  \sum _{i=1}^n m_i = n\cdot m -\sum _{i=1}^n d_i = nm -2m  = m(n-2)$$

and we are done.